# Can dry cracking on tires be repaired?

Tags: tire

In my dry northern climate rubber tires get dry and crack especially if I was lazy and left them out side. 
This happens overwinter where they seem to freeze dry but in summer too if I've left my bike in the sun. 
If the crazing is in a small area on a relatively new tire can it be repaired? ( Like filling it with rubber cement?)

Comment: Cracking tires is caused by sunlight exposure, ozone, petroleum fumes, age, and crummy rubber.  (And, of course, running with the pressure too low.)  Cold weather has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Are you worried about how it looks or it's safety? How many seasons has the bike been left outside? Is this a 35 PSI balloon tire bike or a 110 PSI narrow racing tire? A picture would help.

Comment: Without trying to sound mean, stop leaving your bike outside?  You're not doing the drivetrain or brakes or saddle any favours.  Please add a photo into your question using the [edit] link.